# Where are the gazebo_ros plugin source code

Tags: gazebo, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to find the .cc for the gazebo _ros plugins for ros2.
For example : I can open gazebo_ros_diff_drive_demo.world and work with it,  but it would be nice to see how the plugin was written. I want to modify the .cc plugin file instead of having to write it from scratch.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406146/where-are-the-gazebo_ros-plugin-source-code/) by [Rick_O](https://answers.ros.org/users/112559/rick_o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For Gazebo (previously called Ignition Gazebo): https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz

For Gazebo Classic: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2022-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0